# Is java 8's stream preferable for a loop with instanceof checks?

Tags: loops, java-8, java-stream

I'm just wonder if the stream concept of java 8, which is pretty cool at all, is preferable for the following loop, where I call specific methods due to the kind of object:

```
for (EObject sel : selection) {
  if (sel instanceof A) {
     doSomethingWithA();
   } else if (sel instanceof B) {
     doSomethingWithB();
   }
 }
```

Would you suggest to use the stream API here and if so how would you realize it?

Comment: Simply said: no. It’s not the presence of `instanceof` checks, but the fact that you have a simple “for each element perform this action” kind of loop that doesn’t become simpler nor more readable when you put the action into a Stream use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682526/is-java-8s-stream-preferable-for-a-loop-with-instanceof-checks#comment68595507_40682526) said, your stream would be a pipeline with side effects, so it's clean to use a traditional for loop.

If you are interested on how you can write a fancy `instanceof` you can use

```
someList.stream().filter(A.class::isInstance).forEach(A::doSomeThing);
```